# Changing the dial tone

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to develop application which will allow me to choose a song to be used as my dial tone (the sound that people hear when they call me.. "beep" "beep".

so my question is:

does it possible to replace the default dial tone with other? or its something that controlled from the phone provider only?

Comment: The tone you're asking about is called "ringback" in telephony jargon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671637/how-to-set-ringtone-with-ringtonemanager-action-ringtone-picker Actually it's called ringtone!

Comment: No, dial tone is provided by the network operator.

Comment: @Pavlos The OP is asking about dial tone, not ring tone.

Comment: Ohhhh sorry i thought  it was a mistake cause it's pretty obvious that only the network provider can change the dial tone!